# Cannot send transactions with MetaMask Chrome plugin

Tags: transactions, wallets, metamask

[image: screenshot of what the MetaMask window looks like, without the Send button]

I am trying to send an ETH transaction with the MetaMask Chrome addon, and have done so successfully in the past. However now, there is no "Send" button visible in the window, as shown in the image. I have restarted Chrome, my computer (chromebook), and reinstalled the MetaMask addon........How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you used Mainnet from network drop down? Or any other network in your previous successful transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MetaMask UI has been updated and this is outdated now.

If someone is still using the old UI, you can unzoom the MetaMask extension popup by the following:

1) Visit chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/popup.html in your browser
2) Unzoom a few clicks as you normally would for a webpage

This guide has been taken from https://consensys.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004021392-Changing-MetaMask-s-Popup-Font-Size-Chrome-

Other answer to this post has outdated link.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your font size (zoom level) for the metamask extension was increased, pushing the send button off the screen. There is a guide to changing the popup zoom level here:

https://support.metamask.io/kb/article/9-changing-metamasks-popup-font-size-chrome